# Animate RecyclerView Items according to position

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

in onScrolled() in the OnScrollListener of my RecyclerView I check the distance of the snapped item (SnapHelper.findSnapView()) to the snap position (SnapHelper.calculateDistanceToFinalSnap()) and scale an image in the view according to that.

The goal is to scale images up while they scroll through the snap position in the middle of my RecyclerView.

My problem is, when I scroll too fast (fling) some items do not get updated (mostly dont get scaled down again) until I scroll near them with less speed.
Any idea how to fix that or how to achieve the scaling according to position without this 'bug'?

Thanks in advance :)

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            View v = snapHelper.findSnapView(mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
            float distanceFromSnap = abs(snapHelper.calculateDistanceToFinalSnap(mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager(), v)[0]);

            animate(v, distanceFromSnap);
        }
    });

private void animate(View v, float distanceFromSnap) {
    View image = v.findViewById(R.id.item_active_image);

    float distanceStartAnim = 250;
    float scaleStart = 0.4f;
    float scaleEnd = 1.0f;

    float newScale = scaleStart;

    if (distanceFromSnap <= distanceStartAnim) {
        float percentage = 1.0f - distanceFromSnap/distanceStartAnim;
        newScale = percentage * (scaleEnd - scaleStart) + scaleStart;
    }

    image.setScaleX(newScale);
    image.setScaleY(newScale);
}
```

Comment: can u plz put some  code

Comment: Yes, I added some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to extends RecyclerView and override `offsetChildrenHorizontal(int dx)` and `offsetChildrenVertical(int dy)`. I did something like this before when might help you. Here I scaled downed items as they are scrolling up and exiting the screen.

```
@Override
    public void offsetChildrenVertical(int dy) {
        super.offsetChildrenVertical(dy);

        if (dy == 0)
            return;

        float y;

        int childCount = getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View view = getChildAt(i);
            y = view.getY() + view.getHeight();
            if (y <= view.getHeight() && y >= 0) {
                view.setScaleY(mCalculatedScaleFactor);
                view.setScaleX(mCalculatedScaleFactor);
                view.setAlpha(mCalculatedScaleFactor);
            } else {
                view.setScaleX(1);
                view.setScaleY(1);
                view.setAlpha(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I can overwrite onViewDetachedFromWindow() in the adapter and there I can reset the scaling.

It feels like a workaround but it kind of does the job.

Feel free to post other hints or solutions! :)